# Data cannot retrieve with multiple class name in scrapy using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to get the data from html but response.css, response.xpath and combination is not working whenever I tried to get the "regular-price" data it always says "none"

I need to get the value text of `enter code here` which $17.99

here's my code

HTML

`<div class="price parbase"><div class="primary-row product-item-price product-item-price-discount">
            <span class="price-value">$12.99</span><small class="js-price-value-original price-value-original">$17.99</small>
            </div>
    </div>`

Scrapy python

```
def parse_subpage(self, response):
    item = {
    'title': response.css('h1.primary.product-item-headline::text').extract_first(),
    'sale-price': response.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='price-value']/text())").extract_first(), 
    'regular-price': response.css('.js-price-value-original').xpath("@small").extract_first(),
    'photo-url': response.css('div.product-detail-main-image-container img::attr(src)').extract_first(),
    'description': response.css('p.pdp-description-text::text').extract_first()

        }   
    yield item
```

output should be
regular-price: $17.99

please help thank you!

Comment: Can you share the website?

Comment: https://www2.hm.com/en_us/productpage.0697992001.html try this one this now works still need to get the original prce @KartikeyaSharma

Answer (score 1):

Your link gives me 404, but by your html snippet you need only `response.css('small.js-price-value-original::text').get()`, there is no attribute `small`.

UPD: Hm, seems this data is rendered by JS. Check html code of page and you will see huge json, search by `whitePrice` keyword. You can retrieve such data, forxample with `response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "whitePrice")]/text()').re_first("'whitePrice'\s?:\s?'([^']+)'")`

Comment: still not working, the output is 'regular-price': None, @vezunchik

Comment: https://www2.hm.com/en_us/productpage.0697992001.html try this one this now works still need to get the original prce @vezunchik

Comment: Brilliant use of regular expression here!

Answer (score 0):

If this sniped is the only html you have, you can do:

```
def parse_subpage(self, response):
    item = {
    'title': response.css('h1.primary.product-item-headline::text').extract_first(),
    'sale-price': response.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='price-value']/text())").extract_first(),
    'regular-price': response.xpath('//div/small[contains(@class, "js-price-value-original") and contains(@class, "price-value-original")]/text()').extract_first(),
    'photo-url': response.css('div.product-detail-main-image-container img::attr(src)').extract_first(),
    'description': response.css('p.pdp-description-text::text').extract_first()

        }   
    yield item
```

Btw, the website you provided shows a `file not found`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @vezunchik. If you want to use CSS selector. You can use the below code

```
response.css('script:contains("whitePrice")').re_first("'whitePrice'\s?:\s?'([^']+)'")
```